# jQuery triggering events based on the Hash of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hash, triggers

I'm still pretty new to javaScript/jQuery, so I'm sorry if this seems elementary.

I know that I can change the hash of the url onClick, but can I addClass/removeClass from an element, hide/show an element, fadeIn/fadeOut an element based on the hash in the url?

I'm trying to make a website with all the content on one page (home, about, image gallery, etc...) and then just hide some content and show other content onClick or onHover. But I also want to keep the functionality of a url that can take you to a specific location on the site, so is there a way of using javaScript or jQuery to trigger events based on the hash of the url?

like if hash = #gallery, then show the gallery elements.

Comment: You need to look at: [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location), and possibly [`hashChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/hashchange).

Comment: several plugins that will help manage the url changes and back button history : jQuery BBQ, history.js, address.js...all easily found in google

Comment: I did find jQuery BBQ, but it is incredibly confusing for me. I spent several hours trying to get it to work, but i'm just not very experienced with javaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the page actually reloads (default link behaviour) just make sure a jquery script runs to check the hashvalue.

```
var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Page loaded..
  alert('Do something with the current value');
});
```

If the page does'nt reload just make a $('a').click(); function that responds to the hashvalue like this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop('href').substr(1); //remove hash using substr(1)
      alert('do something else with the '+value+' value!');
      return false; //stop default link behaviour
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using the first string of code you provided and then an if/else statement for the different # values.

```
javaScript/jQuery
var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1)
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(currentValue == "Home") {
    $("#about").addClass("boxshadow");
    $("#info_about").addClass("down");
    $("#info_contact").addClass("up");
    $("#info_pricing").addClass("up");
    etc...
}

else if(currentValue == "Gallery") {    
    $("#door").click();
    $("#about").click();
}


else {
    $("#about").addClass("boxshadow");
    $("#info_about").addClass("down");
    $("#info_contact").addClass("up");
    $("#info_pricing").addClass("up");
    etc...
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you need to check all links that change hash, well

```
$("a[href^=#]").on("click",function(){
     alert("clicked something with hash");
});
```

This triggers every time a link is clicked which starts with `#`